# What rules to follow when designing aggragates in DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot, eventual-consistency, event-storming

I am re-designing my side-project to utilize DDD. I am doing this for learning purposes. It's an application for planning home budget and analysis of spendings. One of functionalities of the app is that user registers expenses and divides them into categories.

I have general question: **how do you design aggregates? What steps to follow?**

Below you'll find steps that I followed that lead me nowhere.

1. I did design-level event storming session for the project up to a step where I have identified invariants and now I am trying to name aggregates. Please consider following slice of event storming artifact as an example:
   [image]
2. I identified relevant entities. Entities relevant to the example:

- Expense
- Expense category
- Expense category group

3. I designed aggregate that fulfills all of the invariants:
   [image]
4. I read this great [article about designing aggregates](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/an-in-depth-understanding-of-aggregation-in-domain-driven-design_598034). According to the article aggragates should follow the rules of:

- Consistency of the lifecycle
- Consistency of the problem domain
- Consistency of the scenario frequency
- As few elements as possible within the aggregation

In case of my aggregate I can see that:

- Consistency of lifecycle rule is violated (because expense is still meaningful when you delete expense category)
- Consistency of the scenarion frequency rule is violated (because expenses will created much more frequent than expense categories will be modified)
- There's also to many elements in the aggregate. The expenses list will be growing.

5. I re-designed the aggregates so that the rules are satisfied. Here's what I've got.
   [image]
6. I realized that now one of the invariants is not part of transactional consistency. Namely the invariant stating *"Expense cannot be assigned to category withdrew from usage before the expense date"*. I know that it is possible to negotiate business rules and replace invariant with some sort of corrective policy but in this case I have no idea of what this policy can be (this is side-project, I am the stakeholder).

And now I am stuck. Please, help. What am I doing wrong?

So far my conclusion are that:

- sometimes I can't have small and well-designed aggregates that satisfy all requirements on consistency
- DDD style application will probably degenerate fast when developed by team with usual structure (more regular/junior developers than seniors/leaders).
- developing DDD style adds huge overhead spent on analysis of which rules should be transactionally consistent, which eventually consistent, how changes to rules impact aggregate structure

Answer (score 0):

Your conclusions are reasonable.

Regarding the invariant:

> Expense cannot be assigned to category withdrew from usage before the
> expense date

I presume you have a method on your Expense that accepts a Category Id and amount, so that this can be called to categorise your expense.

I'd pass in the Category entity itself and go for:

```
public class Category
{
    DateTime? Withdrawn { get; set; }

    public bool IsWithdrawn() => Withdrawn != null && Withdrawn < DateTime.Now;
}

public class Expense
{
    public void Categorise(Category category, decimal amount)
    {
        if (category.IsWithdrawn())
        {
            throw new InvalidOperation("Cannot use category.  It is withdrawn.");
        }

        // Complete the categorisation
    }
}
```

Now, your application layer will retrieve the Category to be passed into the Expense method.

The Expense can then enforce its own invariant.

NOTE:

There is the corner case that a Category gets withdrawn by another process after your application layer has retrieved it but before your Expense is committed.  As this end-to-end process would be very short, my guess is that this is unlikely to be a concern in your use case, but worth considering.

Approaches for ensuring that Category has not been 'withdrawn' before Expense is saved:

**1 - Use a Domain Event**

When the Expense is categorised add an appropriate domain event.  The domain event handler can then perform a just-in-time check about the validity of the Category before the transaction is committed.

**2 - Catch FK Exception**

If 'withdrawn' means deleted from the database, then use the approach from above and when you try to save the Categorisation with an FK pointing to a now-deleted Category then you'll get an FK exception which you can catch and handle.

**3 - Use Concurrency Token**

If 'withdrawn' is just a flag that's put on the Category or Category is not referenced thru a database-enforced foreign key, then you could use a concurrency token.  Various ways of implementing it, but using this approach will tell you if the state of the Category may have changed since you last retrieved it.  If so, you can re-run the command.  If that state change was the 'withdrawal' of the category, then second time around the approach above will enforce the invariant.

Comment: The implementation that you are proposing here is how imagined Expense aggregate from step nr 5. The corner case that you mentioned is the exact problem I am raising here. So far I feel that designing aggregate involves a lot of saying "no" to domain experts. System is either fast or consistent.

Comment: Have added some potential resolutions to the corner case you might want to explore.

Comment: Those are interesting ideas. The idea by withdrawal of category is setting an instant of withdrawal in the category.

Comment: Ad. 1 Use domain events - this doesn't solve the problem because domain event about Category withdrawal might not be available in message broker before transaction commit in Expense aggregate.

Comment: Ad.2 There will not be FK because aggregates will probably be stored in separate storages.

Comment: Ad. 3 This sounds promising. If I got it right the idea is to fetch Category before committing transaction setting category in Expense aggregate and checking "version" attribute?

Comment: In your image you have both the Category aggregate and Expense aggregate in the same domain.  Therefore, for (1) there would not be a message broker.  Domain Events are not same as Integration Events.  Domain Events are handled within the command's transaction.  For (2), if they're in the same domain, then put them in the same database.

Comment: Regarding (3), kind of.  Except that version checking would be done in the Sql command so it can all be handled within the transaction.  Look up Entity Framework's implementation of Concurrency Token for a fuller answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245827/discussion-between-bladositto-and-neil-w).

Comment: @Bladositto re: "fast or consistent", that's the PACELC theorem, which applies to any system (PACELC being "when there's a Partition, you have to choose between Availability and Consistency; Else you have to choose between Latency and Consistency").